# Source for story about a Rabbi being happy to bury Sheimot

Tags: sources-mekorot, shemos-sacred-names, story-identification

I heard a story many years ago about a community that was burying Sheimot. Most of the people were sad/crying, but the rabbi was happy and singing. When they asked him why he was happy, he gave them a parable about two rooms full of toys - one filled with worn out and broken toys because the normal child within played with them and wore them out, the other filled with pristine toys because the child was deathly ill and could not play. The Rabbi said that burying worn out sefarim means they have been well-used, which indicates a healthy Jewish community.

I am looking for a source for this story, particularly to identify who the Rabbi was.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

My father found it in a biography he was reading.

The story is about the Ponovezher Rav (Rav Yosef Shlomo Kahaneman).

[image: book]